# AssertIsNotNone Odd Behavior

Tags: python, django

In django I am writing a test that is checking whether or not a value is null.
This seems to be a pretty standard procedure, but for some reason when i pass a value to the method

`assert self.assertIsNotNone(foo)`

even when the value is most certainly not None, the assertion still fails.

Another odd thing is that the following if block passes even though its the same *intended* behavior as the `assertIsNotNone` function.

```
foo = Load.objects.all().first()
if foo is not None:
    print("Passed")
```

For context, the foo variable in the first example is an instance of a django model. And I repeat, the object is most definitively not None.

Does anybody have any idea what would be causing something like this?

And  if my understanding of the function is incorrect please let me know.

Full code:

```
foo = Load.objects.all().first()

if foo is not None: # passes
    print("Passed")

assert self.assertIsNotNone(foo) # fails
```

Comment: Use `self.assertIsNotNone(foo)`, not `assert self.assertIsNotNone(foo)`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Wow. Thank you. Im gonna see myself out now. (Its been a minute since ive had to write django tests) Should i just close this question?